# 'hoap2' controller crashed. In Webot Simulator

Tags: webots

I am using a Webot simulator to run the hoap2 robot using an inbuilt controller written in C programming language. I am getting an error

WARNING: hoap2: The process crashed sometime after starting successfully.

WARNING: 'hoap2' controller crashed.

And hoap2 is not working in the simulated environment.

Please guide me how can I use hoap2 robot for walking simulation

Comment: The warning tells you that your controller crashed, which mean your `hoap2.c` program is probably faulty. You should try to debug it to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a debugger to understand where and why your controller crashes.

A nice documentation explaining how to debug a controller written in C/C++ is available in the documentation of Webots: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/debugging-c-cpp-controllers